# Access error for opening Excel list attachments on a SharePoint on premise 2013 list

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

We configured Excel Services on SharePoint On premise. We are having a SharePoint 2013 list with Attachments enabled. And a few users are only having permission on the list level, but not site level.
So I have given Contribute level on that list, so whenever that user is trying to access Excel attachment, they are receiving the following error: **Workbook can't be opened, you don't have permissions to open this file.**

If user is having Read Permission on site level, this issue won't occur, but we are not interested in giving permissions on entire site.

Similarly, if I give Contribute permissions on a document library only; this issue is not occurring.

Then why it is restricting only for List Attachments (Only for Excel files we are facing this issue). Any one have thoughts on this?

-> We already tried to add the location of list/web application under Trusted Locations
-> Any other users who have at least Read Only/Read access on site is able to open the list attachment
-> I hope this is not an issue related to Excel Services configuration; as any user having site level permission are able to open the Excel file
-> I'm seeing the same behavior on PROD and DEV environments

Is this a bug with SharePoint or any permission related issue which I need to fix on my site?